# DateTimePicker date selected

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'm having some problems with my Visual Basic Project.

Im making a program which desplays if there come out any new TV series in the US/ Available for download (next day)

(US and Torrent are days in Swedish)

[image]

So I have done that but I want to add a DateTimePicker, so I can select a day and then check whats Available. Well I noticed that the DateTimePicker always starts at the current date so I just added it like so:

```
Dim DateTimePickerDay = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString()

Dim USstatus = "Tomorrow"
Dim DownloadStatus = "Today"

If DateTimePickerDay = "Monday" Then
  StatusLabel1.Text = USstatus
  StatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
  StatusLabel5.Text = DownloadStatus
  StatusLabel5.ForeColor = Color.Green
  StatusLabel6.Text = DownloadStatus
  StatusLabel6.ForeColor = Color.Green
End If
```

But now I want to be able to change the day using the DateTimePicker and see whats available for that day. So I tried to change a Lebel to the day like so:

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
  Me.Label4.Text = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString()
End Sub
```

and then:

```
If Me.Label4.Text = "Monday" Then
  StatusLabel1.Text = USstatus
  StatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
  StatusLabel5.Text = DownloadStatus
  StatusLabel5.ForeColor = Color.Green
  StatusLabel6.Text = DownloadStatus
  StatusLabel6.ForeColor = Color.Green
End If
```

So when the Label says "Monday", which it does if I choose Monday. It's going to show which series are available on Monday. Well this doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone explain for me how I can get this working and what do I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's clear what the "doesn't work" part mean.  What's suppose to happen if the user changes the date?  Maybe post your dtp's ValueChanged event code.

Comment: I noticed that the language in the date picker is not English. Maybe that is causing an issue? Also have you tried putting the '`If Me.Label4.Text = "Monday" Then`' within a onchange for the label? Maybe the `if` statement never fires because it is never called? Thinking about it - I am pretty sure that your issue is that the `if` statement runs onload and not again

Comment: "What's suppose to happen if the user changes the date?"

Then it will "act" like today is the day you just changed. So you are able to tell if there is any series on for example Monday.

Comment: The problem is that you have not told it to do anything when you select a date. You need to either put some code in the `Button11_Click` event that handles the request or - you need to make a listener for the `Label4.text` change (which you can do by double clicking on it in designer). Then put the code that handles the date change in there

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when you can :) glad we sorted that for you

Answer (score 1):

You should base the comparison on the `DayOfWeek` enumeration instead of a string

```
If Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
    ...
End If
```

and also check if the user selected a date in the `ValueChanged` event of the `DateTimePicker` as Chris already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not told anything to listen for a change in the `datepicker1` or the `label4`. I would make it so that when the `datepicker` has changed (every time) the code inside will fire, changing the content. You will need to make some of the variables in the `ContentChanger` sub either public or set them locally else they will not be accessible.

Try something like the following:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    ' When the datepicker1 has changed (date has been chosen).. do something with that date
    ' Get the datepicker's chosen day name
    Dim dayOfWeek As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString()

    ' Update the label to show the user
    Label4.Text = dayOfWeek

    ' Now change the content shown according to the date range
    ContentChanger(dayOfWeek)

End Sub


Sub ContentChanger(dayOfWeek As String)

    If dayOfWeek = "Monday" Then
        StatusLabel1.Text = USstatus
        StatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        StatusLabel5.Text = DownloadStatus
        StatusLabel5.ForeColor = Color.Green
        StatusLabel6.Text = DownloadStatus
        StatusLabel6.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If

End Sub
```